# Text Greater Than ~43,700 Characters Disappears In Datagridview Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, longtext

I have a DataGridView that displays database entries.  The problem is that many of my strings that are very long do not show up in the cells.  The data is there because I can select the cell, copy the contents and then paste them into a text file and they are there.  It is almost as though the Datagridview changes the text color to white once ~43,700 characters are exceeded.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

[Pic-Datagridview not displaying text >~43,700 characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al7dE.jpg)

I have tried setting the cells to wraptext and autosizing the rows and the columns but that actually makes the problem occur at a lower number of characters (makes it worse).
  I also found a very old previous post that is somewhat relevant at "[.NET Windows forms DataGridView Cell text disappears when added programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307352/net-windows-forms-datagridview-cell-text-disappears-when-added-programatically)."  However, that was occurring at 4,563 characters and was not resolved.

Also, I am using Visual Basic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could bind that field to a `RichTextBox` control, positioned in the proximity of the `DataGridView`. Or show just a sample of the text, adding a classic three-dots button, which, upon interaction, lets a user access the complete text in a new window. Something similar to the Visual Studio editor behaviour, when you need to inspect a string variable value.

Comment: The exact limit is 43679 (displayed) and 43680 (not displayed).

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue.

The [DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Paint](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewTextBoxCell.cs,23e73dda899485d3,references) method uses the `TextRenderer.DrawText` method in the called [PaintPrivate Method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewTextBoxCell.cs,df038a70d6c824cb).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26250761/2592875) describes an issue with the `TextRender.MeasureText` method returning invalid values if the text exceeds 43679 characters which is similar to the limit you discovered.  Since the `MeasureText` also involves a call to `DrawText`, these two issues are linked.

A simple workaround would be to handle the [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2) and truncate the formatted string to *magic* string length.

```
Const magicMaxStringLength As Int32 = 43679
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    Dim str As String = TryCast(e.Value, String)
    If str IsNot Nothing AndAlso str.Length >= 43679 Then
        e.Value = str.Substring(0, 43679)
        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this truncation does not alter the underlying cell value.

Edir:  The above allows the DGV to display the text, however it seems the same limitation also applies to the `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`.  Thus the text is not visible while editing.  To overcome this limitation, you can swap a `RichTextBox` for use as the editing control.

```
Private rtbEdit As New RichTextBox
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Dim tb As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = TryCast(e.Control, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
    If tb IsNot Nothing AndAlso tb.Text.Length >= magicMaxStringLength Then
        rtbEdit.Text = tb.Text
        rtbEdit.Margin = New Padding(0)
        rtbEdit.AutoSize = False
        rtbEdit.Font = tb.Font
        rtbEdit.ClientSize = DataGridView1.EditingPanel.ClientSize
        rtbEdit.WordWrap = False
        rtbEdit.Multiline = tb.Multiline
        DataGridView1.EditingPanel.Controls.Remove(e.Control)
        DataGridView1.EditingPanel.Controls.Add(rtbEdit)
        RemoveHandler DataGridView1.EditingPanel.VisibleChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1EditingPanel_VisibleChanged
        AddHandler DataGridView1.EditingPanel.VisibleChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1EditingPanel_VisibleChanged
        RemoveHandler DataGridView1.EditingPanel.SizeChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1EditingPanel_SizeChanged
        AddHandler DataGridView1.EditingPanel.SizeChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1EditingPanel_SizeChanged
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1EditingPanel_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RemoveHandler DataGridView1.EditingPanel.SizeChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1EditingPanel_SizeChanged
    rtbEdit.ClientSize = DataGridView1.EditingPanel.ClientSize
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1EditingPanel_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Not DataGridView1.EditingPanel.Visible Then
        DataGridView1.EditingPanel.Controls.Remove(rtbEdit)
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = rtbEdit.Text
        RemoveHandler DataGridView1.EditingPanel.VisibleChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1EditingPanel_VisibleChanged
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I combined this with [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305681/1458738) so I could be able to also get the full values when copying to the clipboard.